# How to updated rows with 0 condition from another row in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

We have a data frame that looks like this :

```
Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4  Group5  Group6
1         0         1      0       0      0
0         1         0      1       0      0
0         0         1      0       1      0
1         0         1      0       0      0
1         0         0      0       1      0
```

We have binary calculation with respective groups where Group1& 2 subtracted from Group 3 & 4 give Group 5 & 6

We get 0 in Group5 & 6 and we want to update them with Group1 & group 2

We have 100+ lines with similar conditions and need output like below:

```
  Group1    Group2  Group3  Group4  Group5  Group6
    1         0         1      0       1      0
    0         1         0      1       0      1
    0         0         1      0       1      0
    1         0         1      0       1      0
    1         0         0      0       1      0
```

Comment: Do you just want `df$Group5 <- df$Group1` and same for `Group6` ? What is the logic (if there is any) that you are trying to implement here?

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry dude it's my error I have updated now kindly look into it

Comment: I update my answer following condition you added.

Comment: I still don't understand it. Group 3 - Group 1 gives -1 for the last row but you have 1 in group5 column.

Answer (score 0):

Edit by your conditions

```
    data %>%
      mutate(Group5 = abs(Group1 - Group3),
             Group6 = abs(Group2 - Group4)) %>%
      mutate(Group5 = Group5 + Group1 * as.integer(!(as.logical(Group5) | as.logical(Group6))),
             Group6 = Group6 + Group2 * as.integer(!(as.logical(Group5) | as.logical(Group6)))
             )
```

Only update when both Group5 and 6 are 0. If not, please let me know